# OSGi or URLClassLoader?

Tags: java, plugins, osgi

I have rather simple scenario:

My aplication has core jar file that contains my application's logic. This core jar should dynamically watch folder at runtime and when plugin jar is dropped there it should load it and be ready to use it. There may be many plugin jars.

What is in your experience fastest and most maintainable way to implement this? I have 2 suggestions:

1) Some OSGi container, Apache Felix File Install (to watch dir for new bundle). Whereas core jar is installed as bundle into container.

1.1 Problem is how should the core jar detect that newly installed bundle is it's plugin? Is there way to watch for every added bundle and look for some sort of settings with my unique string something like "kalazplugin"? In other words: how to distinct my plugin bundles?

2) Just watching directory for change and when jar is dropped then load it dynamically with URLClassLoader and implement it all myself. I could require some sort of configuration file for each plugin which would specify some settings for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go for OSGi, you could use the *Extender Pattern* to watch any bundles (already installed and installed later) and take any action if you determine that the bundle is one of your plugins. The pattern is easy to implement, especially on OSGi 4.2, which already contains a BundleTracker, but only marginally harder on earlier OSGi versions.

Just google 'osgi extender pattern' and you will see lots of references and implementations.

Comment: Thank you I am gonna use the iPOJO implementatino by Felix. However I think that almost the same functionality can be (theoretically) accomplished by using standard BundleActivator class whereas all my "extensions" implement the same interfaces. Are there any trade offs (except for more code) versus the extender pattern?

Comment: Yes, you can do the same thing in a BundleActivator, however, if you have 200 plugins this will amount to 200 BundleActivators, any change to the plugin registration process will require changing and redeploying 200 plugin bundles! You get the picture.

Comment: The extender pattern is probably not the best choice, although OP doesn't specify what he actually wants to *do* with the libraries once they are installed. Presumably you want to load a class from it? It's better to do this with Objects rather than Classes... i.e. use the OSGi Service Registry. Just define an interface and allow your plugin JARs to publish instances of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to the implementation of 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.directorywatcher' that does exact thing what you want.